# InvalidCastException when accessing a ListBox from codebehind

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I have a listbox with the following xaml which filled from a XMLReader

```
<ListBox Name="listBox4" Height="498" SelectionChanged="listBox4_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Epon}" FontSize="32"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telnum}" FontSize="24" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Beruf}" FontSize="16" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Odos}" FontSize="16"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Location}" FontSize="16"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want to call the phone when i'll select the lisbox item so I created the following class

```
public class PhoneList
{
    public string Epon { get; set; }
    public string Telnum { get; set; }
    public string Beruf { get; set; }
    public string Odos { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }

    public PhoneList(string Telnum, string Epon, string Beruf, string Odos, string Location)
    {
        this.Telnum = Telnum;
        this.Epon = Epon;
        this.Beruf = Beruf;
        this.Odos = Odos;
        this.Location = Location;
    }
}
```

On the event of the selection which is below

```
private void listBox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    PhoneList nPhone = (PhoneList)listBox4.SelectedItem;
    string mPhoneCopy = nPhone.Telnum;
    string mNameCopy = nPhone.Epon;

    var pt = new PhoneCallTask();
    pt.DisplayName = mNameCopy;
    pt.PhoneNumber = mPhoneCopy;
    pt.Show();
}
```

I get the error `InvalidCastException` in the first line of the event.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and inspect `listBox4.SelectedItem` to see what type it really is.

Comment: Also, show where you assign the values from your list to the ListBox (either binding or codebehind).

Comment: i guess replacing the first line with the below code might solve the issue
PhoneList nPhone = (PhoneLsit)(sender as listbox).SelectedItem;

Comment: I dont know how to reply here with the code

Answer (score 0):

From the XAML posted, there is not a collection bound to the `ListBox`. This either means there is no binding, or the binding is being set in the code behind. The following are merely shots in the dark since no additional code has been posted:

**Properly Bind the ListBox**

Assuming a collection is part of the `DataContext`, the collection will need to be bound to the `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}"... />
```

A starting resource: [MSDN: How to: Bind to a Collection and Display Information Based on Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970558.aspx)

**Verify the Object Before Casting**

This may be the case where the item selected is empty, i.e., the first item in the list has no value. In that case, check to see if the object is the type you are expecting before doing anything else:

```
private void listBox4_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var nPhone = listBox4.SelectedItem as PhoneList;
  if (nPhone == null)
  {
    return;
  }

  string mPhoneCopy = nPhone.Telnum;
  string mNameCopy = nPhone.Epon;

  var pt = new PhoneCallTask();
  pt.DisplayName = mNameCopy;
  pt.PhoneNumber = mPhoneCopy;
  pt.Show();
}
```

**Other Thoughts**

I suspect that there may not be a collection bound to the ListBox`; perhaps there is supposed to be some code-behind to set the binding that isn't being executed?

In the end, if none of the above applies to your case, edit the post with the relevant code that is creating the collection and setting the collection as the ItemsSource of the ListBox.